# Unable to docker-compose up any project

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, centos8

Whenever I try to docker-compose up any project I get the following error.
I've tried with and without sudo
I am only having this issue on this machine. I am able to run the same containers on my Mac and Amazon WorkSpace.

```
(myslabs) [austin@localhost myslabs]$ sudo docker-compose up
[sudo] password for austin: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 677, in urlopen
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 392, in _make_request
  File "http/client.py", line 1252, in request
  File "http/client.py", line 1298, in _send_request
  File "http/client.py", line 1247, in endheaders
  File "http/client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
  File "http/client.py", line 966, in send
  File "docker/transport/unixconn.py", line 43, in connect
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 727, in urlopen
  File "urllib3/util/retry.py", line 403, in increment
  File "urllib3/packages/six.py", line 734, in reraise
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 677, in urlopen
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 392, in _make_request
  File "http/client.py", line 1252, in request
  File "http/client.py", line 1298, in _send_request
  File "http/client.py", line 1247, in endheaders
  File "http/client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
  File "http/client.py", line 966, in send
  File "docker/transport/unixconn.py", line 43, in connect
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionRefusedError(111, 'Connection refused'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "docker/api/client.py", line 205, in _retrieve_server_version
  File "docker/api/daemon.py", line 181, in version
  File "docker/utils/decorators.py", line 46, in inner
  File "docker/api/client.py", line 228, in _get
  File "requests/sessions.py", line 543, in get
  File "requests/sessions.py", line 530, in request
  File "requests/sessions.py", line 643, in send
  File "requests/adapters.py", line 498, in send
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionRefusedError(111, 'Connection refused'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bin/docker-compose", line 3, in <module>
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 67, in main
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 123, in perform_command
  File "compose/cli/command.py", line 69, in project_from_options
  File "compose/cli/command.py", line 132, in get_project
  File "compose/cli/docker_client.py", line 43, in get_client
  File "compose/cli/docker_client.py", line 170, in docker_client
  File "docker/api/client.py", line 188, in __init__
  File "docker/api/client.py", line 213, in _retrieve_server_version
docker.errors.DockerException: Error while fetching server API version: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionRefusedError(111, 'Connection refused'))
[142201] Failed to execute script docker-compose
```

I've not been able to find any articles about any similar issues.
I am using Centos 8 running inside of a VirtualBox on Windows.

```
(myslabs) [austin@localhost myslabs]$ docker --version
Docker version 19.03.13, build 4484c46d9d
(myslabs) [austin@localhost myslabs]$ docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.27.3, build 4092ae5d
```

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Trying to connect to a remote `docker` daemon exposed over TCP? Is the `docker` daemon running? Can i.e. `docker ps`?

Comment: So I checked and docker was not running... a rookie mistake. The issue was with the docker daemon config. However now not able to resolve 'deb.debian.org' when building an image. My config looks like this: 
```{
    "dns":["8.8.4.4", "8.8.8.8"]
}
```

Answer (score 43):

I also encountered the same error as you,My problem is that docker does not start.

- check docker status `systemctl status docker`
- `systemctl start docker`
- `docker-compose up` try again
- `systemctl enable docker` to start on boot

Comment: Is there a way to auto check and re issue systemctl start docker 

 ?

Comment: also do `systemctl enable docker` to start on boot

Comment: Also, if your system isn't using systemd, you could instead try the service wrapper: `service docker start`.

Comment: @DJ_Stuffy_K  I recommend you use http://supervisord.org/

Answer (score 15):

If you're on a Mac, it may mean that Docker itself isn't running.  I had rebooted my Mac and Docker wasn't set to automatically launch at login.  You can set this as a Docker preference.

Comment: I had to start Docker Desktop

Answer (score 4):

If nothing works, run:

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose

sudo docker-compose up -d
```

Comment: This line solved my problem with grpc-web sample

Answer (score 4):

If On WSL2 ensure that the docker service has been started, use `sudo service docker status` to check. If it is not running, use the command `sudo service docker start` to get it running before `sudo docker-compose up`

Comment: Interesting. Mine doesn't come up with "start". No error, though.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes docker service is stopped. You can check it and restart.Normally happens if error iscontainer. can pruine and start again.

Comment: Please provide the necessary commands to do this. See here for more information on how to write a good answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Please elaborate what you mean by "Normally happens if error iscontainer". If you have problems with the English language deepl.com might help :)

Answer (score 1):

This issue comes mainly in the case of windows. restart your docker container.

[image]

then run the docker command from your terminal

Answer (score 0):

Please restart docker containers and it will work fine.